# jQuery Mobile dialog won't close after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, dialog

I have a simple JQM (V 1.1.0) listview with an ajax call attached to each item in the list. When the user taps one of the list items, the page behind the dialog is updated with the item they tapped.

The problem is that the dialog doesn't close when the user taps a list item. If I use the (X) Close button in the dialog header, the dialog closes and the page behind the dialog has been updated as expected.

Here's my code:

```
$('body').on('tap', 'a.element', function(event) {

//START LOADING ANIMATION
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

//GET URL FROM MARKUP
bpm.url = $(this).attr('href');

$.get(bpm.url, 
    function(data, result) {
        if(result == 'success') {

            //STOP LOADING ANIMATION
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

            bpm.dataStorage = $(bpm.remoteAppDivName).html(data);


            bpm.dataStorage.trigger('create');


        }    
    },
    'html'
);

//PREVENT DEFAULT BUTTON BEHAVIOR
event.preventDefault();

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$(<dialog element>).dialog('close');` inside your `result == 'success'`.

```
$.get(bpm.url, 
    function(data, result) {
        if(result == 'success') {

            //STOP LOADING ANIMATION
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

            bpm.dataStorage = $(bpm.remoteAppDivName).html(data);


            bpm.dataStorage.trigger('create');

            $('#dialogBox').dialog('close');
        }    
    },
    'html'
);
```

Comment: Thanx for this solution. I was having trouble with the iPhone 3GS and iTouch 4 and your solution helped me close this bug. I initially tried `$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');` after `bpm.dataStorage.trigger('create');`, but that didn't work. Targeting the element directly solved it!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually telling the dialog to close anywhere within your code, which is why it isn't. jQuery can't assume that just because you interacted with the dialog in some fashion, you want it to close...

Try something like:

```
$.get(bpm.url, 
    function(data, result) {
        if(result == 'success') {

            //STOP LOADING ANIMATION
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

            bpm.dataStorage = $(bpm.remoteAppDivName).html(data);
            bpm.dataStorage.trigger('create');

            bpm.closest('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
        }    
    },
    'html'
);
```

Comment: If you have multiple dialogs on a page, this `bpm.closest('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');` could cause an issue if you are not calling the closest one.

Comment: He's binding the event directly to a set of controls which reside on a dialog. The `item.closest('.ui-dialog')` call will, therefore, find the parent dialog on which those items reside. This wouldn't ever cause an issue unless the event was fired on an item which was in a dialog within a dialog - and even then, it would simply close the inner-most of the two (probably the desired functionality).

Comment: @TroyAlford Thank you for the fast response! With jQuery Mobile, you _can_ assume that the dialog will close by tapping a list item. This is already working on 6 of my 8 test devices and on desktop Chrome. You were on the right track, but Bot's solution solved the issue for the 2 troubled devices. I like his solution because I can close the targeted dialog directly. I am working with 2 dialogs in the DOM.

Comment: Ahh nice. :) Good to know! And glad that you found your answer.